# How to install session for RSpec in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec

There is the following spec:

```
  describe 'Some title' do
    before do 
      session[:state] = "12334"
      get '/api/v1/menus', format: :json 
    end


    it 'some text' do
      expect(response).to be_success
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      puts json
    end
  end
```

It code tests the following controller's action:

```
class Api::V1::MenusController < ActionController
  def index
    render json: session
  end
end
```

But I've got the following exception: "undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass". How can I fix it? How can I make a new example of a session? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
describe 'Some title', :type => :controller do
```

RSpec needs to know you are doing "controller things" in your test. You indicate this as above or by placing the test in *spec/controllers*.